# Reactjs Onclick replace the existing component with another one - example

Tags: reactjs, react-native

did any one had this situation where you should replace an existing component with totally a different one - like an accordian.

```
<ComponentA /> (+ image) - click on this
<ComponentB /> (- image) -
```

Should I use states here?
And Should I be having separate images on each component, but how to deal with positioning the images exactly at same location. Any simple example on how to communicate between such components would be helpful.Thanks.

Comment: You can make use of router as well

Answer (score 1):

yes you need to use states to manipulate the visibility of components. in your render function you could do something like this

```
render(){
    return this.state && this.state.showComponent1 ? <ComponentA /> :<ComponentB />
}
```

and in your button `onClick` event you could set it up like this

```
onClick = () => this.setState({showComponent1: !this.state.showComponent1})
```